# No overload method for ToString takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to format a datetime to a string of the form "c", by using the ToString method:

```
string end = evt.End.DateTime.ToString("c", DataController.culture);
```

DataController.culture is a reference to a valid culture object and evt is an Event object from the Google Calendar v3 API. I am sure DateTime is of the DatetTime class because the debugger says so in the type of the object.

However I keep getting the issue mentioned in the title, why? Even the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) show how to use that method but somehow I can't:

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("d MMMM", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX")));
// Displays 29 agosto
```

Comment: Change the code to `evt.End.DateTime.GetType().FullName`.  What is the full name of the type that you believe is a DateTime?

Comment: In looking at the docs those are virtual, which would lead me to believe they might be actually different types at the time of access https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1EventDateTime.html

Comment: I had not considered that the type might be nullable; silly me.  That would explain the observed behaviour, and the test I suggested -- printing the runtime type -- would not have indicated the problem in the typical case.  (Because GetType() would either crash, if the value was null, or return typeof(DateTime) if it was not.)

Comment: But this happens at compile time, does it mean i have to cast it to another type or how do i go about this?

Comment: Also, how come this is off-topic? Afaik I am asking a question about an specific implementation in a specific language, nothing opinion based or stuff like that. I hope it's a troll.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1Data_1_1EventDateTime.html) indicates that the property you're attempting to `ToString()` is actually a `System.Nullable<DateTime>`, which has different usability considerations from a normal `DateTime`. In order to invoke the `ToString` method you wish, you need to retrieve a concrete `DateTime` struct from the nullable one provided to you - in your case, by doing the following:

```
string end = evt.End.DateTime.Value.ToString("c", DataController.culture);
```

Mind you, you normally will want to first check that your nullable object (eg. `evt.End.DateTime`) actually has a value by checking the `HasValue` property before invoking `ToString()` or any other method or property.

Comment: Nice catch! I note that in C# 6 you could also solve the problem elegantly with the nullable member access operator.

Comment: I actually tried that (without knowing anything about Nullable objects) and because the IDE suggested Value as a property, however I get an "operation not permitted" error or something among those lines, is it because the object is null at runtime? do i have to safe-check something before? Again, I am new to C#.

Comment: Generally speaking, a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown if the object were indeed null. Could you please update your question with the code that's throwing the error you described?